# Is it possible to copy an JavaScript object from the dev console such that I can create an exact copy of it for tests?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I'm dealing with some some code relating to handling paste events, where the copied data comes from a variety of sources.

In it, I'll capture the paste event, and do some processing on it.

I now want to write some tests for this code, and it'll be a lot easier if I can just capture the paste event that I console.log.

Is this possible?

ie. I can reproduce a 'good enough' event like:

```
const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer();
dataTransfer.items.add("...", "text/plain");
const pasteEvent = new ClipboardEvent("paste", {
  clipboardData: dataTransfer
})
```

I'm hoping the dev tools can help do this for me.

Comment: Since the internal state of any object may depend on a lot of things, including other things you'd also have to copy, environments you'd have to recreate, and internal details you simply don't have access to: generally _no_.